# Display File Sizes with the Appropriate Denomination in PHP

Tags: php, math, precision, filesize

Using PHP, what's an easy way to display file sizes with the appropriate denomination in regard to the amount of bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a little function for this:

```
function filesize_exact($iSize, $iPrecision = 2, $bSpace = true) {

    // By Gabriel Nahmias (gabriel@terrasoftlabs.com)

    // Measure certain byte ranges in descending order.

    $sUnit = "bytes";

    if ($iSize > 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) {
        $sUnit = "PB";
        $iSize /= 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    } else if ($iSize > 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) {
        $sUnit = "TB";
        $iSize /= 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    } else if ($iSize > 1024 * 1024 * 1024) {
        $sUnit = "GB";
        $iSize /= 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    } else if ($iSize > 1024 * 1024) {
        $sUnit = "MB";
        $iSize /= 1024 * 1024;
    } else if ($iSize > 1024) {
        $sUnit = "KB";
        $iSize /= 1024;
    }

    if ($iPrecision > 0 && $iPrecision != NULL)
        $iSize = round($iSize, $iPrecision);

    // Make sure bytes is always spaced out; could be changed.

    return $iSize . ($bSpace || $sUnit == "bytes" ? " " : "") . $sUnit;

}
```

Works for me.  Has a couple of nice options.  You could extend it to encapsulate any range of sizes so long as it's in descending order because that's how the logic is set up here and it's suitable.  See http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/FileSizeConversionTable.asp for a decent list of file size denominations.